# What good do I initialize global/static variables to 0/NO/nil explicitly?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, static-variables

[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/FrameworkImpl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001286-1005930) reads:

> You should initialize static variables to ensure that they are merged
>   into the __data section of the __DATA segment as opposed to the __bss
>   section. If there is no obvious value to use for initialization, use
>   0, NULL, 0.0, or whatever is appropriate.

Does it mean that __bss is in a sense bad compared to __DATA? But in my understanding, __bss is good for it results in smaller binary executables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

__bss stores uninitialized data, while __data stores variables that were initialized manually. The program loader has to initialize __bss when program loads and this takes some extra time while variables from __data are loaded as is.

Comment: I suppose a __bss section is recorded as a (start_address, length) pair in the executable and cleared to zeroes by CPU instructions. So I don't see why it takes longer than loading the same number of bytes from secondary storage to the main memory, as is the case of __DATA.